# box shadow is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am giving box with java script at runtime.But its not working. I have created a method and called that method onpage load but it does not works .

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aps123/kwb4K/4/)

```
div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

function generateShadowHtml(){

    $(".boxShaddow").css("-webkit-box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #0000"); 
     $(".boxShaddow").css("-moz-box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #0000"); 
       $(".boxShaddow").css("box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #0000");

}
```

Comment: `#0000` is not a valid colour string. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: it works with `#000`: http://jsfiddle.net/kwb4K/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment already said it, but I wanna clearify it for you.

You code does work, but as suggested, "#0000" is no valid html color.

You need to know that color codes with a hashtag "#" are always hexadecimal.

So you may use something like "#FFADEC" or else. For the color black and white, you may shorten "#FFFFFF" and "#000000" to "#FFF" and "#000".

Also notice, that every 2pair of the color code may be represented as a rgb state as well.

For example:

With color code "#FFADEC" you would have the rgb code "rgb(255, 173, 236)", because:

1. FF in hex is 255 in decimal
2. AD in hex is 173 in decimal
3. EC in hex is 236 in decimal

For more info check http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

Color format is wrong:

```
function generateShadowHtml(){

    $(".boxShaddow").css("-webkit-box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #000"); 
     $(".boxShaddow").css("-moz-box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #000"); 
       $(".boxShaddow").css("box-shadow","6px 3px 5px 4px #000");

}

generateShadowHtml();
```

replace to `#000`